# How to load JSON into field of Silverstripe Dataobject

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

A recent Silverstripe version upgrade to 4.3.1 appears to have broken some functionality where a dataobject is loaded as JSON into a Textfield.

The object looks like this:

```
class Foo extends DataObject 

  private static $db = [
    'Name' => 'Varchar',
    'Description' => 'Text',
    'Models' => 'Text',
  ];
```

Then there's a function to load the object with JSON generated from a form request:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getBody(), true);
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->update($data);
```

Here's an example of the JSON `$data`:

```
"Name":"Test",
"Description":"Wangle fangle blurble wurgle.",
"Models":{
   "fish":{"trout":10,"salmon":15,"sturgeon":20},
   "vegetable":{"carrot":1,"cabbage":2,"leek":3},
   "sauce":{"chipotle":6,"tomato":4,"soy":2}
 }
```

Until very recently the "Models" structure would get saved into the "Models" field as text:

```
 "fish":{"trout":10,"salmon":15,"sturgeon":20},
 "vegetable":{"carrot":1,"cabbage":2,"leek":3},
 "sauce":{"chipotle":6,"tomato":4,"soy":2}
```

But now we get the following error:

`DataObject::setField: Models only accepts scalars at /var/www/example/vendor/silverstripe/framework/src/ORM/DataObject.php:2648`

Line 2640 in DataObject.php says:

```
If this is a proper database field, we shouldn't be getting non-DBField objects
```

Has there been a recent security fix that is now blocking the attempt to load a JSON object into a field?

Can anyone help with saving the Models JSON into the text field?

Comment: Possibly this issue is related: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/8814 I see some possible workarounds: 1) escape the json 2) make your own DBField class that accepts non-scalar values. you currently pass an arary to it or 3) adjust the depth of your json_decode according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php . Maybe `json_decode($request->getBody(), true, 1)` does the trick? See also: http://php.net/is_scalar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@wmk is bang on here, this is expected behaviour to prevent security vulnerabilities (see [SS-2018-021](https://www.silverstripe.org/download/security-releases/ss-2018-021)). The change in 4.3.1 is to prevent you from inadvertently allowing users to insert non-scalar values into your data models when you've specified your DB field to be a scalar type.

In your case you're trying to write an array into a text field, which is correctly being blocked by silverstripe/framework.

The easiest workaround for you here is to re-encode the parts of your data array that you know you want to store as a JSON text blob, e.g.:

```php
$data = json_decode($request->getBody(), true);
$data['Models'] = json_encode($data['Models']); // re-encode as JSON before saving
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->update($data);
```

This will ensure that you're still writing JSON as text into your Text field.

Also as @wmk mentioned, another viable option is to write your own DBField which accepts non-scalar values and takes the responsibility of safely writing them into the database. This would be useful if you're writing a DBField that deals with [GIS or spatial data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-types.html). In your particular example I think you can get away with ensuring it's still encoded as a string as my example.